# WSUS - approving updates for patch testing

Tags: wsus

We're starting to use WSUS to patch our computers. I setup a patch testing group of 10 XP boxes and 10 Win7 boxes to roll out all the patches to prior to dispersing them company wide.

So I went to All Updates and set Approval filter to Unapproved and Status to Failed or Needed. Selected the updates I wanted and clicked Approve and select the Group I wanted and approved the updates.

Now I want to release those same updates for the entire company, all my groups but since I have already approved the updates I can no longer see them?? Under Unapproved and Failed or Needed there's nothing there.

How can I find the updates that I just approved for patch testing so that I can approve them for the rest?

If I change the Approval filter to Approved and Status to Failed or Needed I get way too many updates, I just want the ones I just approved not all of them.

There must be a way to approve the same updates to multiple groups at different times right?

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to find the patches by selecting an unpatched PC, and looking at what updates it requires, then approve them from there.

Comment: Ok I did that and found the Status report but it only lets me do 1 update at a time. Just looking at this New Update View...thinking I could create a new one that will show me just my patch testing group....?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Custom Update View for the property "Updates approved for selected group(s)", and then select the group for which  you approved the updates.

Select that View in the console, and set the filters to Approval="Approved" and Status="Any".

Select the updates to add additional approval groups and click on "Approve" to add the additional groups in the approval dialog.